# How to make multiple rug plot in R that shares X and Y axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame of 10 patients. Each patient has five different parameters. I would like to generate a multi rug plot as shown in Tufte's "The visual display of quantitative information", p.135 Here's the image of the rug plot:

[image].

I have tried with ggplot and gridExtra, but it wasn't much of use, because I cannot leave "blank spaces". In this case all the x=Var 1 graphs should be vertically aligned (as they share X axis) and the ones who share y axis should be horizontally aligned.
Is there any package or technique that could help?

Thank you.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID= c(1:10),
  Var1 = rnorm(10),
  Var2 = rnorm(10),
  Var3 = rnorm(10),
  Var4 = rnorm(10),
  Var5 = rnorm(10)
)
plot1 <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) 

plot2 <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Var3, y = Var2)) 

plot3 <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Var5)) 

plot4 <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Var3)) 

plot4 <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Var4))
```

Comment: This is not a plot type that I have seen being produced in R before. I can see a few different ways of doing it, but they are fairly involved. It is made more difficult in your example because you have Var3 as both an x variable in plot2 and a y variable in plot 4. It seems from the attached picture that each variable should only be on a single axis. It might help if you could post some more realistic data, as I think any solution on your example data will be complex and difficult to generalize to your real data set.

Comment: It would help if you would show us how to get each of the scatterplots.  Then we can think about how to put them together.  I think I may have an idea.  Also if you will use set.seed(1234) we can generate the data.

Answer (score 4):

As Allan mentions, this plot is pretty involved. Here is my interpretation of Tufte's plot, but note that *all* x/y axes are shared and we can't really share them per row or column of panels.

First we setup some dummy data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  ID= c(1:10),
  Var1 = rnorm(10),
  Var2 = rnorm(10),
  Var3 = rnorm(10),
  Var4 = rnorm(10),
  Var5 = rnorm(10),
  Var6 = rnorm(10),
  Var7 = rnorm(10)
)
```

Next we write ourselves a little helper to do points and rugs in one go.

```r
pointrug <- function(mapping, data, sides = "br", ...) {
  list(
    geom_point(mapping = mapping, data = data, ...),
    geom_rug(mapping = mapping, data = data, ..., outside = TRUE, 
             length = unit(5.5, "pt"), sides = sides)
  )
}
```

Then we define some layout that we're going to use. We'll use `ggh4x::facet_manual()` to actually use this (disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x).

```r
design <- "
 ##A
 #CB
 DE#
 #F#
"
```

And lastly, we make the plot, being careful that we place the right x and y variables per facet.

```r
ggplot(df) +
  pointrug(aes(Var3, Var4), data = ~ cbind(.x, facet = "A"), sides = "br") +
  pointrug(aes(Var3, Var5), data = ~ cbind(.x, facet = "B"), sides = "lt") +
  pointrug(aes(Var2, Var5), data = ~ cbind(.x, facet = "C"), sides = "br") +
  pointrug(aes(Var1, Var6), data = ~ cbind(.x, facet = "D"), sides = "br") +
  pointrug(aes(Var2, Var6), data = ~ cbind(.x, facet = "E"), sides = "tbl") +
  pointrug(aes(Var2, Var7), data = ~ cbind(.x, facet = "F"), sides = "tr") +
  ggh4x::facet_manual(
    vars(facet), design, 
    heights = c(2, 1, 3, 1.5),
    widths  = c(1, 1.5, 2)
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And this is `+ theme_test() + guides(x = "none", y = "none")`:

[image]

Comment: Very nice Teun. I thought about adding an answer that mapped everything onto a single panel because I couldn't see a good way of doing it with facets, but this is much better.  Perhaps some theming to match the original would be perfect?

Comment: Yeah `theme_test()` goes well here to match the Tufte look. It's questions like these that make me wonder why I didn't implement the `facet_grid()`-like locking of scales to rows/columns. Then I look at the source code and remember that is very hairy already to build that on top :')

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.  I don't think that you could display more than 4 variables.  That is:
The x and y variables defining the grid;
The x and y variables defining the scatterplots.

Although not as beautiful as Tufte's  this gets you part of the way.

```
  
     ggplot(mtcars,  aes(wt, qsec)) +
     geom_point(size = .5) +
     geom_rug() +
     facet_grid( rows= vars(gear), cols = vars(carb)) +
          theme_bw() +
          theme(strip.text.y = element_blank(), 
                strip.text.x = element_blank(),
                strip.background = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                panel.border = element_rect(color = "lightgray")) +
          ggtitle("qsec by wt, by gear and carb")
```

You would want to figure out how to hid the empty plots. And to use the template options in ggplot2 to remove the excess ink.
Also you could look at the patchwork package if you want to put together each of the separate plots in a more custom way.

[image]